# How to generate 52 weeks from current date using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How to generate 52 weeks from current date using postgresql

for example: from current_date(i.e todays date) to 52 weeks .

Comment: Something like `select dt::date
from generate_series(current_date, current_date + interval '52 week', interval '1 week') as g(dt)` maybe?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *generate_series* which allows you to define range (start, stop) as well as the step interval like: *generate_series(startDate, endDate, stepBy)* **so depending on output format you are after** you could do something like:

`SELECT generate_series(
         current_date, 
         current_date + interval '52 weeks', 
         interval '1 week'
       ) weeks;`

which would generate something like this:

`weeks
2017-05-24 00:00:00
2017-05-31 00:00:00
2017-06-07 00:00:00
...`